# Why does my Files Object doesn't get rendered in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

i'm relative new to React, and don't get the point why my files Object doesn't get displayed. In the collection_files there is an array with References to each file Document

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  getFirestore,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import CollectionContext from "../components/CollectionContext";

const CollectionViewer = () => {
  const [selectedCollection, setSelectedCollection] =
    useContext(CollectionContext);
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState();
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const db = getFirestore();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const collectionDoc = doc(db, "collections", selectedCollection);
      const snapshot = await getDoc(collectionDoc);
      const data = snapshot.data();

      if (!data) {
        console.log("no data");
      }

      setCollection(data);

      const fileDocs = await Promise.all(
        data.collection_files.forEach(async (fileRef) => {
          const fileDoc = await getDoc(fileRef);
          console.log(fileDoc.data());
          return fileDoc.data();
        })
      );

      setFiles(fileDocs.map(doc));
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [selectedCollection]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="m-10">
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <h1 className="leading-10">{collection?.collection_name}</h1>
          <h1 className="leading-10">{collection?.collection_id}</h1>

          {files.map((file) => (
            <div key={file?.id}>
              <h5>{file?.file_name}</h5>

              <p>Downloads: {file?.file_downloads}</p>

              <p>Size: {file?.file_size}</p>

              <p>Owner: {file?.file_owner}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CollectionViewer;
```

This is my Console Log & Errors, i get the point that collection_files is undefined, but why?:

```
CollectionViewer.jsx:32 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection_files')
    at fetchData (CollectionViewer.jsx:32:14)
fetchData @ CollectionViewer.jsx:32
await in fetchData (async)
(anonymous) @ CollectionViewer.jsx:42
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 11 more frames
Show less
CollectionViewer.jsx:32 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection_files')
    at fetchData (CollectionViewer.jsx:32:14)
fetchData @ CollectionViewer.jsx:32
await in fetchData (async)
(anonymous) @ CollectionViewer.jsx:42
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:25154
invokeEffectsInDev @ react-dom.development.js:27351
commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:27330
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27056
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 10 more frames
Show less
CollectionViewer.jsx:31 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at fetchData (CollectionViewer.jsx:31:38)
```

Thank you in advance!

Should retrieve and display dynamically, file objects which are saved as a reference in the firestore

Comment: `collection_files` is not undefined, `data` is.